# Semget Permission denied when not root, server config issue?

Tags: c++, configuration, centos, semaphore

I have a C++ application that uses semaphores that I'm trying to call through a PHP "exec" command. I can run the application successfully when logged in as "root" from the terminal, however when apache attempts to run it (as user apache), it fails with a "Permission denied" error.

I did a "chwon apache:apache prog" and 777 the permissions of it to test, it still fails.

The weird thing is that this exact application works perfectly fine through apache on my local development environment. Both environments are Centos 6.4 (Final) x86_64 and run PHP as the same user.

I'm out of ideas, I'm not sure what else I can do.

Here is the relevant portion of my code.

```
void landw(char* path, char* retType)
{
startLocking:
    int semid,count;
    struct sembuf op;
    semid = semget((key_t)KEY,10,0666|IPC_CREAT);//Fails here
    if(semid==-1)
    {
      perror("error in creating semaphore, Reason:");
    }
...
```

I've even altered to the "semget" line to this as a test, still a no go.

```
semid = semget((key_t)KEY,10,0666|IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the issue, the problem was SELinux.

SELinux was disabled on both of my development machines but enabled on the production server.